# how to read the html file contents and replace using php

Tags: php

```
$file_handle    = fopen($htmlFileName,"r+");
while (!feof($file_handle)) 
{
    $templateData = fgets($file_handle);
    str_replace("#softwareVersion#",'Data',$templateData);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to buffer values. Add something like `$buffer = ''` before loop and `$buffer .= $templateData` in the end on each step.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make use of the easy way ?

```
$data = file_get_contents($htmlFileName); // You are reading here
$replacedCont = str_replace("#softwareVersion#",'Data',$data); // You are replacing the content
file_put_contents($htmlFileName,$replacedCont);// You are writing the replaced content to the file.
```

**EDIT :**

> I want to replace so many strings of html page using PHP

Well you didn't mention this on your question. You can make use of arrays of data to be replaced. Do like this...

```
$content_to_be_replaced = array('#softwareVersion#','#software#','#hardware#');
$content_to_be_replaced_with = array($exportMetaData['params']['softwar‌​eVersion'],$exportMetaData['params']['software']‌​,$exportMetaData['params']['hardware']);

$total_replaced_content = str_replace($content_to_be_replaced,$content_to_be_replaced_with,$data);
```

Comment: yes..I want to create a new html file and that "#softwareVersion#" replaced with some data

Comment: $replacedData=str_replace("#softwareVersion#",$exportMetaData['params']['softwareVersion'],$templateData,$htmlFileName);
    file_put_contents($htmlFileName,$replacedData);
   $replacedData1=str_replace("#software#",$exportMetaData['params']['software'],$templateData,$htmlFileName);
    file_put_contents($htmlFileName,$replacedData1);
   $replacedData2=str_replace("#device#",$exportMetaData['params']['device'],$templateData,$htmlFileName);
    file_put_contents($htmlFileName,$replacedData2);
   $replacedData3=str_replace("#hardware#",$exportMetaData['params']

Comment: Why are you passing the filename in the `str_replace()` O.o ??

Comment: Still it is not replacing